# Access: filtered form results in to a temp table

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have an Access Form that lists addresses and details related to those addresses. It is filtered manually by staff using the standard menus to come down to a list of relevant addresses.

I'd like to output those filtered results to a table (temp table) so that I can use it to create mailings.

Is this possible and if so what sort of code should I be using for a button.

TIA
MK

Comment: You need to provide more info.

Comment: Welcome to the board.  I see you've read the [tour] page - _questions about an actual problem you have faced. Include details about what you have tried and exactly what you are trying to do._.  As @onetwo12 said - can we have some more info please.

Answer (score 1):

When users filtering records, they are changing `.Filter` property of form. Text of this property is equivalent of WHERE clause of SQL. So, all you need is to create `INSERT ... SELECT...` SQL query with the same source as record source of form and use filter text for WHERE clause. Something like this:

```
Dim str_filter As String
Dim str_recSource As String

str_recSource = Me.RecordSource
str_filter = Me.Filter

CurrentDb.Execute "DELETE * FROM MyExportTable"
If str_filter = "" Or Me.FilterOn = False Then
    CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO MyExportTable SELECT * FROM (" & Replace(str_recSource, ";", "") & ") as t"
Else
    CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO MyExportTable SELECT * FROM (" & Replace(str_recSource, ";", "") & ") as t" & " WHERE " & str_filter
End If
```

Comment: Thanks Sergey S, that works perfectly. Much appreciated.

Comment: Please mark the answer as accepted if it helped to solve the problem, it will be useful for others.